# ArcGIS93Rest for Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-online, openlayers, arcgis-rest-api

In Openlayers v2 I could get a map from an ESRI server that was not a cached service using code similar to below

```
var arcims = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("MyName",
    "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/export",
    {
        layers: "0,1,2"
    });
```

How do you do the same using Openlayers v3 I can't same to find the right function in `ol.source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArcGIS REST API hasn't been included in the OpenLayers 3 code yet. People are [discussing](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/654) its importance and it is expected to have an implementation in a later version. Until then, you can try to stack with an ArcGIS WMS server or use OpenLayers 2.

OpenLayers 3 WMS example: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/tr0s6uno/

Code:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({ 
            url: "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/WMSServer",
            params:{
                LAYERS:"0,1,2",
                FORMAT:"image/png",
            }
         })
    })],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-115, 45],
        zoom: 0
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers-3.9.0 adds support for ArcGIS Rest Services via the [ol.source.TileArcGISRest](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileArcGISRest.html) ([source pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3263)).  [TileArcGISRest Example](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/a81150508dd1f15ab4dd99ee1ef6f748a33a37fd/examples/arcgis-tiled.js)

OpenLayers-3.16.0 introduced [ol.source.ImageArcGISRest](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageArcGISRest.html) to serve a single static image ([source pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3880)).  [ImageArcGisRest Example](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/18a29ea6d3bf47f15060e35bfbabafc23303b5a9/examples/arcgis-image.js)